# obtener la fecha del dia que se pulsa en fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

hola estoy intentando obtener la fecha del dia que se pulsa en fullcalendar pero no me funciona. Me muestra bien el año y el mes, pero el dia siempre me pone que es el dia 1.He intentado hacerlo con getdate() y en el dayClick: function() pero el dia siempre me aparece que es el dia 1. ¿como puedo hacerlo?
un saludo.
este es mi codigo:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Calendario</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0   /css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.min.css">
<script src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col-7"><div id="CalendarioWeb"> </div></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#CalendarioWeb').fullCalendar();
});
$('#CalendarioWeb').fullCalendar({
  dayClick: function() {
    //window.location="http://localhost/calendario/newfile.html";
      var moment = $('#CalendarioWeb').fullCalendar('getDate');
      alert("The current date of the calendar is " + moment.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
  }
});
$('#CalendarioWeb').fullCalendar('next');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

ya lo he solucionado. He sustituido este codigo:

```
$('#CalendarioWeb').fullCalendar({
dayClick: function() {
//window.location="http://localhost/calendario/newfile.html";
  var moment = $('#CalendarioWeb').fullCalendar('getDate');
  alert("The current date of the calendar is " + moment.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
}
});
```

por este:

```
$('#CalendarioWeb').fullCalendar({
  dayClick: function(date) {

      alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
  }
});
```